# System DSN vs user DSN

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, odbc, dsn

Every new computer in my company undergoes the same software installation process; one program in particular needs to access a MS SQL Server database via ODBC. The program is then used by multiple domain users on the same computer at different times.

On Windows XP machines, I simply set up the ODBC connection as a *System DSN*. No matter what user logged in, the connection would work for him, and my job was done.

Recently, we get more and more Windows 7 machines, and this method doesn't seem to work anymore. The program doesn't recognize the connections I set up in *System DSN*, but it does recognize those in *User DSN*. The problem I have with this is that every time a user logs in on a computer for the first time, I get a call and need to install his or her own DSN.

What's the reason this works on XP, but not on 7? Have I been doing it wrong from the start?

**Update:** Maybe the reason isn't Windows 7, but the fact that the new computers run a 64-bit OS. I say this because when I ran a test application ([source code here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/connect-to-mysql-database-via-odbc-using-a-dsn-part-i/)) on 64-bit Windows 7, accessing the *User DSN* worked fine, but accessing the *System DSN* gave the following error message:

> IM014: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

The [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that this happens when a 32-bit driver is accessed on a 64-bit computer, or vice versa. This could very well be the problem, because when I switched the test application to 64-bit, the System DSN could be accessed.

The question now is: Why does this happen for System DSN, but not for User DSN - are there different drivers installed for the two? That would mean that I won't be able to use the System DSN any longer, because I have no influence on the software we need to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft article of [Managing Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the following :

> To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit
>   platform, use `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. To manage a data
>   source that connects to a 64-bit driver, use
>   `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`. In Administrative Tools on a
>   64-bit Windows 8 operating system, there are icons for both the 32-bit
>   and 64-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog box.
>
> If you use the 64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that
>   connects to a 32-bit driver, for example, Driver to Microsoft Access
>   (*.mdb), you will receive the following error message:
>
> > *The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application*
>
> To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove the DSN.

Your application is evidently 32-bit. Have you used the right odbcad32.exe to define the DSN ?

Comment: No, I haven't; I had no clue there were two versions. I'm blown away - it works. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I haven't handed out the bounty earlier; I thought this would happen automatically with marking your post as the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary anymore on Windows 7 64 bit. Running either 'version' brings up the same console with the same defined DSNs. Simply using the run dialog and typing in 'odbcad32.exe' and defining a DSN, I was able to access said DSN via my scripting languages.

Comment: @AndrewPK: The poster was running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

User Rights:
Be sure, that the User has the ability to access the System-DNS or User-DNS.
The situation here was, that Lotus-Notes ran as a service under the SYSTEM-User.
There was no connectivity to ODBC. We changed the User for the Service and that solved the 
Problem.