# How do I stop the following error from occuring? "A connection attempt failed" (see full error in body)

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, odbc

I am getting the following error on an excel workbook which has a data connection to a sql database.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The connection string looks as follows;

```
DSN=COMAPNY1;Description=Dashboard OBDC;UID=USERNAME1;PWD=PASSWORD1;Trusted_Connection=No;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=WORKSTATION1;DATABASE=LiveData;
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.

It is running on a windows 10 laptop connected by wireless, wondering if this is dropping and causing the issue, or if it is a simple change to the way the ODBC is setup.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error indicates connection was either rejected and/or it could not be found (DNS).  The database on a remote or local computer?

Comment: The connection string does not look right. When you strip out overridden and duplicate information, all that is needed is "DSN=COMAPNY1", the rest was already included when you defined the DSN. If that doesn't work, then the server is unreachable. Did you test the connection string when creating? And did you match the created DSN to the server regarding 32/64-bit (see [link](https://superuser.com/questions/465734/system-dsn-vs-user-dsn))?